# Octave: xlsread function undefined + causes octave crash

Tags: io, crash, octave, xlsread

I'm new to this, so I'll try to explain clearly.

I'm using Octave (4.x) to process data and I want to import an Excel file. Excel is installed on my laptop as well.

```
[num,txt,raw] = xlsread(input.rootdir);
```

When the function is called, the following message appears:

```
warning: Functions for spreadsheet style I/O (.xls .xlsx .sxc .ods .dbf .wk1
etc.)  are provided in the io package.  See <http://octave.sf.net/io/>.

Please read <http://www.octave.org/missing.html> to learn how you can
contribute missing functionality.
warning: called from
    __unimplemented__ at line 524 column 5
    CreateInvoices at line 18 column 3
error: 'xlsread' undefined near line 18 column 5
error: called from
    CreateInvoices at line 18 column 3
>>
```

The warning appears that the I/O package is not installed. However, the package is listed when I call 'pkg list' in command line, so it seems to be installed correctly.

[pkg list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cg6gf.jpg)

There are some other topics on stack overflow with a similar content, but they seem to be solved with proper installation of the I/O package.

If I try to call 'pkg load io', Octave crashes immediately.

I tried to use other functions to import data (csv, textread, ...), but I always lose my text data. So that is not really helpful.

Does anyone have some advice for me?

Thanks in advance for the reply!

Best regards,
Lode

Comment: That's a very long-winded way to basically ask "Why does my octave crash when I load the io package". :p   In any case, how did you install the package? Are you sure you've installed dependencies correctly? Have you tried installing from the forge? Do you get any error messages? What about if you run in the console (i.e. `octave --no-gui`)

Comment: Is this on GNU/Linux or windoze? Which distribution and Octave version (not just 4.x...) and how have you installed "io" and Octave? (from source tarball?)

Comment: I have the 4.0.3 version of Octave and I run it on Windows 7. Based on the documentation and the 'pkg list', everything is installed as it should be.
Honestly, I don't know anything about installing packages and so on. I have a very good background in Matlab, but when it comes to installing things like this, I'm a complete noob.. Either documentation is poor or I do not know where to find the correct documentation to solve this issue. Probably the latter is more likely. I have installed Octave based on online tutorials. Besides the crashes when I try to import xls/xml, Octave works perfectly!

Comment: What "online tutorials" have you used for installing Octave? It should be easy as download an installer from https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/octave/windows/ and execute it and finish the dialogs. Perhaps you've installed an incompatible JRE? Do you see any error message if you do `pkg load io`

Answer (score 0):

I've just done this, but in Linux (Xterm windows with bash). I had to install liboctave-dev package first, then the io octave package. Then the call to 'pkg load io' before using it. But need to make sure to install with root privileges or the package won't be found by a shared Octave installation. Of course, this was not on windows but might provide some clues.